# AngularJS inherit a single scope from another controller

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to inherit a single scope from one controller to another controller via $controller?

Here is my current code:

```
var peopleApp = angular.module('peopleApp', []); 

peopleApp.controller('indexController', function($scope){
    $scope.sampleVar = "Hello World";
    $scope.sampleVar2 = "Hello World Again";
});

peopleApp.controller('addController', function($scope, $controller){
    $controller('indexController', {$scope.sampleVar: $scope.sampleVar});
    alert($scope.sampleVar);
});
```

I know this will throw an error because of "$controller('indexController', {$scope.sampleVar: $scope.sampleVar});" that should be "$controller('indexController', {$scope: $scope});" but the concept or desired return is there.

Comment: Do you want to inherit only 1 value ($scope.sampleVar) from scope?

Comment: It should be like that

Comment: this is not a good design `$controller('indexController', {$scope.sampleVar: $scope.sampleVar});`

Comment: If you want to share a single property between 2 controller make a service.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body ng-controller="parentController">
    <div ng-controller="childController1">
    </div>
   <div ng-controller="childController2">
    </div>
</body>
```

You can inherit properties form parent controller to childController1 and childController2

Angularjs internally maintaines scope hierarchy via ng-controller directive where you defined in dom. For More detials in https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

Another way is Inject $rootScope inside controller and access properties from
anywhere in your app controllers

```
var app = angular.module('sample',[])
app.controller('controller1',function($rootScope,$scope){
$rootScope.parent ="I am visible in any controller";
})
app.controller('controller2',function($rootScope,$scope){
//here you can access rootScope property using rootScope or Scope 
// Because rootScope is parent for all scope object
// Angular scope protochain is like javascript protochain it looks from child to parent scope
   console.log( $rootScope.parent);
   console.log($scope.parent);

})
```